# Why do I have to declare specific bold/italic variants for web font?

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

I'm trying to use the Ubuntu font on a website. I am using the FontSquirrel @font-face generator. On computers where the Ubuntu font is installed everything works fine when I simply have css like `font-family: Ubuntu`. But on other computers it won't work unless I explicitly state which particular variety I want like `font-family: UbuntuRegular` or `font-family: UbuntuBoldItalic`. It is the same situation across all browsers.

It is silly to have to declare weight and style every time. Isn't there some way to just declare the general font family and have the bold and italic faces used automatically when needed?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure but I'm also using a custom font 'SansationRegular' on windows using font generator and if I don't specify the state (style, weight) or specify the weight:bold it becomes thin (looks normal) but when I use font-weight:normal it becomes a little bold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most @font-face generators set font-weight and font-style to normal and use separate declarations for each weight/style for backward compatibility. But you can rewrite the declarations to use the same family name for each variation, changing only font-weight and font-style within each where appropriate, e.g.:

```
@font-face { /* Regular */
font-family: 'Klavika';
src: url('klavika-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('klavika-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('klavika-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('klavika-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face { /* Bold */
font-family: 'Klavika';
src: url('klavika-bold-webfont.eot');
src: url('klavika-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('klavika-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('klavika-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
}
```

So that H1 should inherit the bold weight without the need to specify the weight:

```
h1{ font-family: 'Klavika';}
```

456 Berea St has a good post detailing the implementation (and compatibility): http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/font-face_tip_define_font-weight_and_font-style_to_keep_your_css_simple/

Comment: Excellent. And nice article. For some reason I wasn't cluing in that you set the font name to whatever you want with the @font-face declaration. Font Squirrel should update their stylesheet in my opinion, or at least offer an alternative version.