# Adding Custom Font to Shopify Issue

Tags: css, fonts, shopify, font-face

For some reason the custom font that I am trying to implement on my Shopify site is not working at all. I uploaded the font as an asset and used the code in our theme.scss file:

```
         @font-face {
           font-family:'Neue-Haas-Grotesk', sans-serif;
           src: url(Linotype-NHaasGroteskDSStd-65Md.ttf);
           font-weight: 900;
           font-style: normal;}
```

I then added codes such as the one below to have it be displayed on certain parts of the site:

```
   .site-nav { font-family: "Neue-Haas-Grotesk" !important; }
```

I tried this exact template of code with an Arial Black ttf file that I uploaded as an asset but for some reason this font is not working what so ever. Any suggestions on how to make this work properly on Shopify now and in the future for any site?

Comment: You should convert the font to webfont and use woff/woff2 (https://transfonter.org/) instead of only ttf.

Comment: thank you for this suggestion! i'll go ahead and try that right now!

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert your font file to *.woff* or *.woff2* using any online converter.
2. Add this code snippet to `{% style %}` tag in *theme.liquid* file.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "fontName";
  src: url({{ "fontName.woff2" | asset_url }}) format("woff2"),
       url({{ "fontName.woff" | asset_url }}) format("woff");
  }
```

3. Add `font-family` property to your CSS code.

```css
.class {
  font-family: fontName;
   }
```

Note: If font name is more than one words, use quotations. `"font name"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to make sure that you have a correct URL for your `@font-face` declaration. Asset files will be served from Shopify's CDN (Content Delivery Network), so you will want to use the `asset_url` filter to get the correct address.

This should hopefully do the trick:

```
@font-face {
   font-family:'Neue-Haas-Grotesk', sans-serif;
   src: url({{ 'Linotype-NHaasGroteskDSStd-65Md.ttf' | asset_url }});
   font-weight: 900;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: oh okay got it! thank you! do you by any chance know if it mattes whether its a ttf or otf file that's uploaded?

Comment: TTF and OTF should be generally interchangeable. Here are some articles I found on different fonts formats for web: https://css-tricks.com/understanding-web-fonts-getting/ https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp

Comment: it looks like that change worked!! i added both a woff and woff2 file. however, the font should be appearing much thicker/bolder than it does right now. i even changed the font-style to "bold" but it didn't seem to change anything. Do you have any suggestions on how I could fix this?

Comment: I believe you will need to upload the bold version of the font as well.  If you look at this StackExchange question, note that the answer uses different font files for the regular and bold declarations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243419/why-do-i-have-to-declare-specific-bold-italic-variants-for-web-font

Comment: ohh okay got it. thank you so much for all your insight Dave! I also wanted to see if you by any chance know why a particular font change for a section of the site is not budging? for some reason some of the button's fonts are not changing at all. even when i input code like: .btn--secondary,.btn--tertiary, .btn--secondary-accent, .btn.shopify-payment-button, .btn.shopify-payment-button__button--unbranded {
  font-family: "Neue-Haas-Grotesk", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900 !important;

Comment: I would use the browser's dev tools to see the CSS rules applied to the element (and by extension, if rules I'm setting are being overridden by other styles).  To do this in most browsers, simply right-click on the element on the page and select 'Inspect' from the context menu.  This should bring up a developer window that includes the HTML structure (you can select different elements by clicking on their code) alongside a CSS window.  In the CSS window, styles that are being overridden or that have bad syntax should appear crossed-out.  Searching/filtering for 'font' should also help.

Comment: If you need help getting started with the inspector, this article might help (written for Chrome): https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css

Comment: hey dave, i actually have ben using that tool! it just strangely is not changing the font for the product title on the cart page (cart__product-title) and the ".product-form__cart-submit, .shopify-payment-button .shopify-payment-button__button--unbranded" button. i put those exactly in my css with "!important" and they still won't change for some reason

Comment: Very strange... Do you have a preview link that you're able to share?

Comment: hey dave! was able to fix the issue by removing the custom font in the existing css and adding "!important" to the additional css code added for each section of the site's font! thank you so much for helping look into this :))

Answer (score 0):

I'm also little new to Shopify, loooking an answer to uploading a custom font that I've bought for my site. Now, as far i understood so far they need to be uploaded to shopify cdn and then needs to be imported in the css.

Can someone please guide, where exactly to upload the file (I've .otf file only, sufficient?), post which i can follow the answer above in this thread.

Comment: You can follow this link
https://support.weareunderground.com/article/272-how-do-i-add-a-custom-font-to-my-theme